# MySQL how to select 1 if MAX() equals current row SUM() aggregate value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions, max

I'd like to select a new column named `sliced` (value can be `1/0` or `true/false` it doesn't matter) if `area` of the current row equals `MAX(SUM(c.area))`, that is *flag* the row with highest aggregate value:

```
SELECT p.name AS name, SUM(c.area) AS area
FROM City AS c
   INNER JOIN Province AS p ON c.province_id = p.id
      INNER JOIN Region AS r ON p.region_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = ?
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.name ASC
```

I've tried adding to the selection `area = MAX(area) AS sliced` or even `area = SUM(MAX(c.area)) AS sliced` but i'm getting a syntax error. I've to admit i'm not so good in SQL. Thank you.

Comment: If area of the current rows not equals MAX(SUM(area)) you want to skip `sliced` column at all or return `0`/`false`?

Comment: Return `false` or `0`. I just need to flag the current max value!

Comment: You can't perform nested aggregation. You will have to do a subquery. I'll put it when I find some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with just one group by:

```
set @row := 0;
select name, area, sliced
from (
    select name, area, (@row := @row + 1) = 1 as sliced
    from (
        SELECT p.name, SUM(c.area) AS area
        FROM City AS c
        INNER JOIN Province AS p ON c.province_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN Region AS r ON p.region_id = r.id
        WHERE r.id = ?
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 2 desc) t1
    ) t2
order by 1;
```

The inner query (`t1`) does the group by and orders by total area largest first.
The next query (`t2`) gives the first row a value of `true` for column `sliced`, all other rows `false`.
The outer query orders the rows in the way you want - by name.

Since there's only one table scan and group by, this should be very efficient.

Comment: Maybe adding some indentation will help us to understand your solution (which seems the best to me atm)? Thanks

Comment: @Gremo Good idea - I've indented it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, this should do it. Creates a pseudo-column which returns 1 when the area is the same as max(area) without any conditions to restrict your selection.

```
SELECT name
     , area
     , case area when max_area then 1 else 0 end as sliced
  FROM ( SELECT name
              , area
              , max(area) over (partition by 1) as max_area
           FROM ( SELECT p.name AS name
                       , SUM(c.area) AS area
                    FROM City AS c
                   INNER JOIN Province AS p ON c.province_id = p.id
                   INNER JOIN Region AS r ON p.region_id = r.id
                   WHERE r.id = ?
                   GROUP BY p.id
                   ORDER BY p.name ASC )
               )
```

**EDIT** As @Glide says you can't perform nested aggregation so `sum(max(area))` won't work and you need to perform these operations one query at a time.

Comment: Why you `GROUP BY name, area` in the second nested query?

Comment: In your example, the value returned by MAX(area) will be the MAX() across that group, not the whole table.  As you are grouping by Area, the MAX() of Area is implicitly the same value.  This means that sliced will be 1 for every record.

Comment: Ach you're correct... changed it to a `partition by` analytic function @Gremo, which is actually correct...

Comment: I didn't know MySQL had windowing functions.  But assuming it does, you don't want to partition by area, that again gives MAX(Area) for each unique value of Area - the same as before.  Is it legitimate to do `OVER (PARTITION BY 1)` or maybe `OVER ()`?

Comment: @Dems, it is indeed legal, I use it often and I'm obviously being extremely stupid this morning. Thank you.

Comment: Reading about MySQL's implementation of this, I think you can remove the middle layer of the subquery, and put the `MAX() OVER` straight into the outer most query?

Comment: Possibly, I prefer to do it this way as you can very easily see what's happening ( Plus I don't have a DBMS at the moment to check whether it'll work! ), but that is just a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: @Dems: *‘Reading about MySQL's implementation of this…’* – where exactly, pray? There's not a word about *window*, *windowed*, *windowing*, or *analytic* functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html), for example.

Comment: @AndriyM - Checked my browser history and it was a blog about MS-SQL rather than MySQL.  I can get Oracle pages and MS-SQL mages, but nothing about using OVER in MySQL.  (And now I can't unvote, oops)

Answer (score 0):

As comments have mentioned, you'd have to check all the values against another query.  This is normal practice in SQL.

```
SELECT
  p.name AS name,
  SUM(c.area) AS area,
  CASE WHEN SUM(c.area) = (SELECT MAX(area) FROM <repeat your query here>) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
  City     AS c
INNER JOIN
  Province AS p
    ON c.province_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
  Region   AS r
    ON p.region_id = r.id
WHERE
  r.id = ?
GROUP BY
  p.id
ORDER BY
  p.name ASC
```

The biggest downside to this is that you've had to repeat the code, which is just messy and a maintenance headache.

The alternative is to insert all the data into a temporary table, with the sliced field being 0 for all records.  Then update that table, setting sliced to 1 for the record(s) with the highest area.

Comment: I prefer Ben's windowing function version using `MAX(area) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)`